# Finding element attribute with XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to get the PurchaseDate from the following XML structure (a receipt from an in-app purchase in Windows Phone):

```
<Receipt Version="1.0" CertificateId="..." xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2012/store/receipt">
  <ProductReceipt PurchasePrice="$0" PurchaseDate="2013-05-20T19:27:09.755Z" Id="..." AppId="..." ProductId="Unlock" ProductType="Consumable" PublisherUserId="..." PublisherDeviceId="..." MicrosoftProductId="..." />
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
        <DigestValue>...</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
  </Signature>
</Receipt>
```

My code goes as follows:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(receiptXml);

string date = doc.Root.Element("ProductReceipt").Attribute("PurchaseData").Value;
```

This keeps raising an access error, because `doc.Root.Element("ProductReceipt")` is null. Why is XDocument not getting the ProductReceipt element?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add namespace to your LINQ to XML query. Because you have default namespace declaration at the root node `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2012/store/receipt"` you also need to specify it in your query.

Next code shows an example:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(receiptXml);

XNamespace xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2012/store/receipt";

string date = doc.Root
                 .Element(xmlns + "ProductReceipt")
                 .Attribute("PurchaseDate")
                 .Value;

Console.WriteLine(date);
```

prints:

```
2013-05-20T19:27:09.755Z
```

There is also a namespace agnostic approach:

```
string date = doc.Root
                 .Elements()
                 .First(node => node.Name.LocalName == "ProductReceipt")
                 .Attribute("PurchaseDate")
                 .Value;
```

Comment: Note that if you want the date as a DateTime, you can simplify it to: `var date = (DateTime) doc.Root.Element(xmlns + "ProductReceipt").Attribute("PurchaseDate");`

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks for noting. Although OP has specifically indicated string as data type for date. It can be changed if he want to.

Comment: Great and concise answer! Thank you VERY much! @MatthewWatson's note was also helpful, thank you!